# Как сделать чтобы функция применялась ко всем прописанным классам?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы функция применялась ко всем прописанным классам видео?

```
var myVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".video__item");
function playPause() {
    if (myVideo.paused)
        myVideo.play();
    else
        myVideo.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас практически ответ в вопросе.
Чтобы "функция применялась ко всем", нужно этой функцией пройтись по всем элементам с классом.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".video__item").forEach(function(e) {
  if(e.paused)
    e.play();
  else
    e.pause();
});
```